# I needed to have a dynamic report that the data is from another worksheet. What is the right formula?

Tags: excel

I have this worksheet named database and another worksheet named report.

[image]

[image]

The database worksheet is connected to a SQL server. I get my data from there.

What i want to do is to automatically fill the information of the reports worksheet from the data of the database worksheet dynamically. The problem is i don't know where to start i am new to formulas like VLOOKUP i just know the basics of excel so it is very helpful if you can give me a jump start.

Comment: The Vlookup function is quite easy to use - In its simplest form, the VLOOKUP function says:
=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

However, I am not sure this is what you need for your particular application. Are you looking to retrieve one specific user ID or do you want to have all men and all women in two separate tables?

Comment: For the latter, you may want to consider using VBA